# How to use multiple PHP version using Apache and not using FPM?

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I have two PHP versions installed on the server `7.2` and `7.4`. Both are enabled as well.

There is a project running using PHP `7.2`. And I need to run a new project using PHP `7.4`. As I've mentioned, I don't use PHP-FPM. After some research, I should use `a2dismod php7.2` and `a2denmod php7.4` to stop `7.2` and start `7.4` version. But in this case, the current working project would stop working, since it's compatible with ver `7.2`.

So, any idea how can I config Apache to handle two different projects running on the same server one using PHP `7.2` and the other using `7.4` without using PHP-FPM?

Comment: IIRC you can't run more than one mod_php at a time, so you're going to need to move to FastCGI one way or another, and the recommended way is PHP-FPM.

Comment: It's also a good time to update both projects to 8.1+.  Another option would be to run 2 cloud servers on different subdomains, but you might as well update to 8,1+ for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use PHP as an Apache module, AFAIK, you can only load one PHP module per server instance.

However similar what is done with PHP-FPM, you can run two Apache server instances. One configured with the PHP 7.2 module, the other with the PHP 7.4 module.

Given the PHP 7.2 moduled Apache is the current server instance, it would proxy for the virtual host of the PHP 7.4 application to the new, second Apache server instance.

This would be comparable with Nginx and two PHP-FPM, just a different layout with Apache and Apache.

```
         +----------------------------------------------------+
         |                       +-------------+ + pool #1    |
         |                ,----> | PHP-FPM 7.2 | + pool #2    |
         |   +-------+ <--'      +-------------+ + ...        |
  WAN <====> | Nginx |     FCGI                               |
         |   +-------+ <--.      +-------------+ + pool #1    |
         |                '----> | PHP-FPM 7.4 | + ...        |
         |                       +-------------+              |
         +----------------------------------------------------+
```

```
         +-------------------------------------------------+  
         |    +-------------+            +-------------+   |
  WAN <=====> | Apache #1   | <--------> | Apache #2   |   |
         |    |.............|    HTTP    |.............|   |
         |    | mod PHP 7.2 |            | mod PHP 7.4 |   |
         |    +-------------+            +-------------+   |
         +-------------------------------------------------+
```

AFAIK you can only use the standard utilities like a2denmod(1) for the main server instance. Therefore make yourself comfortable with the server configuration, Apache is well documented and I personally like its configuration a lot. It's perhaps I started with Apache 1.3 ca.

However as it's 2023, Nginx + PHP-FPM is a very nice combo. Vanilla Nginx is a pretty decent powerhorse.

Comment: Nice answer thank you. It would be great if you also show the diagram of `Apache` and FPM, how would it look like? Also, out of curiosity, what do you mean by "pool"? Do you mean "project"?

Comment: Yes, sure: Take the Nginx diagram and replace "Nginx" with "Apache" and you're done. Pool is a sub-organization within a PHP-FPM master. You can have a pool per project for example. Allows you to control under which user/group it executes, dedicated PHP configuration and environment and also processing limits etc..

Comment: Got it, as my last question, do you know in which config file of Apache is specified the PHP version? You know, I have two versions of PHP installed/enabled on the server, but Apache uses `7.2` (saying so based on `phpinfo()`) as the web server and uses `7.4` for the cli (based on `php -v`). In which Apache's config file those versions are mentioned?

Comment: CLI is unrelated to Apache configuration, however you *could* control this via the PATH environment parameter that is available per process. Cf. _[PATH in ENVIRON(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/environ.7.en.html#PATH)_.

Comment: And the comment by Dave is not wrong. Just bring the PHP 7.2 app to PHP 7.4, you can continue to run then one server. Then you can experiment with the second server and run PHP 8.2 on it. Depends a bit if you have object intensive code, perhaps start with PHP 8.0/8.1 first, if the quick-start on PHP 8.2 doesn't go well. Most things are only deprecations, log them in 7.4, they are easy to fix and then the code should be upgrade safe.

Comment: You know Hakre, when I switch to `7.4` on the server, the second project will work well, but the first project complains about pdo undefined. I don't know how many extensions should be installed on `7.4` too to make the first project working. The first project is live on production and on avg we have over 500 concurrent users.

Comment: PDO you should have, but one of your previous comments made me thinking: Why not fan-out from Apache with FCGI? As you mention the modules PDO is an extension, so it should be possible to have either multiple PHP-FPMs and/or pools w/ configuration. So you can start with one FCGI setup on a dedicated vhost in Apache and give it a try. This would spare a complete second Apache instance. Sort of a combination of the two exemplary/schematic layouts.

Comment: And IIRC your original problem with the PHP versions: [Configure the **platform** setting in composer.json configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/composer-platform-dependencies.md) with the target PHP version (target = production version, that is Apache/FPM), then composer does not inherit the PHP version from the PHP binary it is executed with (PHP CLI). This is also a reminder in each project what the current PHP version for the project is (on production). And then finally just do not run composer on the webserver. Run it elsewhere and just deploy the codez + configuration.

Comment: Yeah I tried it by the composer too with no success. [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIrSo.png). I've clearly mentioned to use "php 7.4.33", but still it says [it requires PHP version ">= 7.4.0"](https://panel.lamtakam.com/)

Comment: If you're having a hard time to figure out how platform actually works in the Composer configuration, there is always `--help` for each of the composer commands and you find command-line switches where you can override that. When in doubt, consult the Composer documentation. You'll figure it out.